# RDS [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-rds, cakephp-3.0

I have an instance in Amazon RDS  with many databases, all of them accessed by PHP (cakephp 3.9) without any issues in Elastic Beanstalk.

I have a main user that can access all of them, and each DB has its own user as well.

**The issue?**
I have created a new database in the RDS instance that returns a 1045 error (auth error), but I can connect with the same credentials to SequelPro or another kind of DB manager. The error is kind of weird because the credentials are 100% correct (the same I use in the Db manager).

I have exactly the same error with both users (root and DB user). As I commented above, I have many Dbs in the same instance, and all of them are accessible without issues (the error only happens for this new database).
The error is this:

```
default-log-channel: ERROR: 2022-09-15 04:19:57 Error: [PDOException] SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'myuser'@'172.61.15.102' (using password: YES)
```

Here are the dumps I got when checking the dsn query string,both dbs in the same instance (obviously I have changed pwds and names)

**mysql:host=project-testing-1.xxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com;port=3306;dbname=my_db;charset=utf8**

```
**First query, the one that returns the error.**
    array (size=15)
      'driver' => string 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql' (length=26)
      'persistent' => boolean false
      'host' => string 'project-testing-1.xxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (length=55)
      'port' => string '3306' (length=4)
      'username' => string 'root' (length=13)
      'password' => string 'xxxx^sdsdsdsd@j&sdsd&' (length=30)
      'database' => string 'my_db' (length=17)
      'encoding' => string 'utf8' (length=4)
      'timezone' => string '+0:00' (length=5)
      'cacheMetadata' => boolean true
      'log' => boolean false
      'quoteIdentifiers' => boolean false
      'name' => string 'my_db' (length=17)
      'flags' => 
        array (size=3)
          12 => boolean false
          1000 => boolean true
          3 => int 2
      'init' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'SET time_zone = '+0:00'' (length=23)
          1 => string 'SET NAMES utf8' (length=14)
```

**The second one works fine (same instance).**

```
**mysql:host=project-testing-1.xxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com;port=3306;dbname=-testing-db;charset=utf8**

array (size=15)
  'driver' => string 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql' (length=26)
  'persistent' => boolean false
  'host' => string 'project-testing-1.xxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com' (length=55)
  'port' => string '3306' (length=4)
  'username' => string 'root' (length=15)
  'password' => string 'xxxx^sdsdsdsd@j&sdsd&' (length=40)
  'database' => string 'testing-db' (length=24)
  'encoding' => string 'utf8' (length=4)
  'timezone' => string '+0:00' (length=5)
  'cacheMetadata' => boolean true
  'log' => boolean false
  'quoteIdentifiers' => boolean false
  'name' => string 'testing-db' (length=7)
  'flags' => 
    array (size=3)
      12 => boolean false
      1000 => boolean true
      3 => int 2
  'init' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'SET time_zone = '+0:00'' (length=23)
      1 => string 'SET NAMES utf8' (length=14)
```

**UPDATE**: I just realized that the issue it is not in a particular database, **the issue is about the second database connection**, the first always runs OK, but the second one returns an auth error (even with the root user).

**DSN query string.**

```
   mysql://root:xxxxxxx@project-testing-1.xxxxx.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/testing-db
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a solution, but **I was able to use a different db server**.
It means that I did not change my PHP code but I moved the db to a different provider outside AWS RDS and it works!!!, there is something in AWS RDS that block the database's connections (I did not create the infrastructure in there). The only thing I can say 100% sure, is that the issue it is on the server (RDS instance), not in my code, and not in the credentials. If someone has a possible solution (or an idea) please let me know.